# Xbox one sound options

Tags: xbox-one

So an Xbox One is HDMI only by the looks of it and I want to use an LCD screen with no speakers. What are the options for sound output?

Comment: I am aware of the optical output. I also may try a hdmi set top box with hdmi out as sound going through rca out.

Comment: What do you intend to use for speakers? Do you have a receiver with speakers? Speakers with analog input? RCA input? 3.5mm jack? Do you intend on using headphones?

Comment: I intend on using any option I could. Rca or 3.5 mm are preferred though I figure someone had to ask the question about sound and one.

Comment: Headphones, a t.v, bluetooth speakers, an Alienware. Anything. A headset or Kinect if it was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

- If you have a receiver with an HDMI/Optical input, you can connect those directly to your Xbox with the appropriate cables. If you have speakers/headphones with optical input, you can connect those to the console directly as well.
- You can use the [Xbox One Stereo Headset Adapter](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/headsets/stereo-headset-adapter) to connect 3.5mm headphones directly to your controller.
- You can get an optical to analog audio converter to output the sound to speakers with RCA input.

Comment: Stereo headset adapter was the way to go. $37AU.

Comment: On phone, close question?

Comment: I will if I get to a P.C or work out how.

Comment: However if there are more ways, as I only by chance found the coin to get the adapter. Please feel free to add for the ones who have to improvise.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your speaker system.
If the system has HDMI in/out, you can do it like this:
[image]

If its Toslink in, you can do it like this:

[image]

As far as i know, there is no way to get a 3.5 mm jack out from an xbox one.

Answer (score -3):

Xbox controller to 3.5mm out to rca then to amp. Easy.

Comment: Please give more details instead of enumerating abbreviations.

Comment: Old Xbox controllers can have an attachment you can buy, to allow 3.5mm connection to them,(headphones). So a cable from a $2 shop, rca to headphones(3.5mm) should allow sound from your controller to your stereo. New controllers already have the 3.5mm connection.